# No Python at '\python" после преобразования проекта с Ursina в bat-файл

Tags: python, ursina

По документации Ursina https://www.ursinaengine.org/building.html я преобразовал свой python-файл в bat-файл. При запуске батника в log.txt ошибка: No Python at '\python" (в pyvenv.cfg я указал путь \python).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скрин папки  build